# Shell-independent way to find the shell's initialization (.shellrc) file?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, zsh

The brute-force way to do this would be something like:

```sh
if [ $SHELL = /bin/zsh ]; then
  rc="$USER/.zshrc"
elif [ $SHELL = /bin/bash ]; then
  rc="$USER/.bashrc"

...

elif [ $SHELL = /bin/fish ]; then
  rc="$USER/.config/fish/config.fish"
else
  warn_user()
fi
```

But that runs into all kinds of problems with DRY, and totally fails if there's some random new shell you missed.

Is there something that looks like $SHELLRC that tells you where to find the resource file the current shell runs at startup? Or if not, is there a more elegant way to implement something to the effect of the `if/elif/.../elif/else` statement above?

Comment: This seems like an XY Problem. Can you provide more details about what exactly you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to read the current shell's resource file to see if it contains a comment that another program leaves behind when it runs (I know this is bad practice, but it's third party and I can't choose not to use it).

At this point, I'm mostly just interested in whether something like this *does* exist, than whether it's a good practice.

Comment: Many shells call the `...rc` file on startup automatically for interactive sessions – for Bash, for example, an interactive non-login shell reads `~/.bashrc` as its only startup file.

Comment: If you are just searching for a known string like that comment you mentioned then why not search *all* files that could be a shell rc file? For instance using `grep '# comment' .*rc .*profile`.

Comment: Semi-portable:`$SHELL -xc exit 2>&1 | grep -E 'rc|profile'` and do some more filtering. It quite common to source many resource files.

Comment: Does that other program leave behind anything other than comments? E.g. does it set any environment variables or define any aliases?

Comment: _totally fails if there's some random new shell_ : Every solution will fail on some random new shell. If I give you a shell I invented, there is no way to know what kind of initialization files it will allow; you would have to read the docs. First of all, you need to identify which shell you are running, and `SHELL` does not tell you this reliably.